# Getting 403 Forbidden error in Spring Boot security despite CSRF being disabled

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

For some reason I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error from Spring Boot when I try to do anything with it. I currently have the following in my `configure` method of my `SecurityConfiguration` class:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*", "/console").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

I'm new to this part of Spring boot so not sure if this is what's causing it.

Comment: and when you enable your debug logs they say? also i dont really understand why you are adding custom login filters when there are already built in filters you can customize. By adding custom filters you are basically opting out of spring security. This is most likely CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out... I'm an idiot. This isn't caused by CSRF at all... It was caused by the fact I'm British and I spell what should be Authorization as Authorisation in my AuthenticationFilter which was choking up everything else.